# Ignore filters on metric (in row)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, dax

I just realized that a lot of my calculations are off because I have one metric which relies on looking at many years of data.

However, on all PivotTables where I have to show this metric (which should ignore filters) - it applies the date ranges of the PivotTable.

How would I set just this metric (referenced in a row with year columns) to ignore all filters?

EDIT: I have already tried ALLEXCEPT() but this seems to work just for columns and this metric is added in Values to be shown across rows split into columns by years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure:=
CALCULATE(
    <expression>
    ,ALL( 'FactTAble' )
)
```